# 404 script errors in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, http-status-code-404

Trying to get rid of 404 errors in Wordpress

AM getting over 50 404's that reference .js files like this:
https://armonklimo.com/web/20160328222349js_/https:/livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_46548/wp-content/themes/CherryFramework/js/camera.min.js?ver=1.3.4

https://armonklimo.com/web/20160328222349js_/https:/www.armonklimo.com/wp-content/plugins/menubar-templates/Superfish/superfish.js?ver=4.3.3

https://armonklimo.com/web/20160328222349js_/http:/www.armonklimo.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js?ver=3.51.0-2014.06.20

https://armonklimo.com/web/20160328222349js_/http:/www.armonklimo.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=4.0.3

So many 404's...never ran into this, or at least .js related
This is not preventing my website from loading but is keeping our Google Adwords campaign at bay since it looks menacing.

I have tried a few different things such as resaving my permalinks, going into Google Developers but nothing has helped. First timer here. Thanks to everyone here.

Comment: You're repeating the "Https" section twice, that's incorrect, remove the second "https://armonklimo.com", after that you'll have to do some digging into the back end of wordpress to determine why the URL's don't resolve, this is probably not the right site to help you with this...

Comment: Thanks David, I am a novice when it comes to coding, I appreciate it!